# SSO using Spring and CAS

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, cas, spring-security

I am trying to implement SSO utilizing Spring + Acegi + CAS + Tomcat. Can you please tell me if there is any documented procedure  to do it. I have been searching all over but could not find one. I have learnt from your blogs that you have achieved sso. The front end for my application is Adobe Flex/AIR.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Van

Answer (score 1):

I used this tutorial [Using CAS with Acegi](http://www.mallsop.com/downloads/Using_CAS_with_Acegi.ppt).

Comment: The link above is simply a single powerpoint with this url - http://www.mallsop.com/downloads/Using_CAS_with_Acegi.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it using this [documentation](http://mattfleming.com/node/269) 
Some of the changes I had to implement are described [here](http://hons82.blogspot.com/search/label/CAS)